# Do I need to get a residence permit in Germany if my type D visa covers the length of my stay?

Tags: germany, residence-cards, internship

I'm currently in Germany with a type D internship visa that covers the length of my stay (validity dates from arrival to departure, with duration of stay listed as XX).

If it makes any difference, the remarks section on my visa says:

> Praktikum nach § 15 Nr. 5 Beschv bei [**COMPANY NAME**] in [**PLACE**]
>
> Aufenthaltsdauer entspricht Gültigkeit

I've registered/have insurance/etc. I'm just wondering if getting a residence permit is mandatory.

Thank you!

Comment: I suspect it is not.  Have you tried asking at the Ausländerbehörde?

Answer (score 2):

From all I can tell it depends on how long you are staying. **If you are staying for more than 90 days, then you need to get a residence permit.**

Sources:

- [Justlanded Germany](https://www.justlanded.de/english/Germany/Germany-Guide/Visas-Permits/German-residence-permits)

  > Residency permits are handled by your local immigration office (Ausländeramt). In order to apply for a residence permit, first register your residence at the local Einwohnermeldeamt (registration office), where you can also get the application forms for a residence permit.
- [Study in Germany](https://www.study-in.de/en/plan-your-studies/requirements/visa-and-residence-permit_26604.php) (sponsored by DAAD and federal ministry, refering to study stays but I suspect strongly the same holds for an internship)

  > You have to apply for a residence permit if you
  >
  > - Are not a citizen of an EU member state, Iceland, Liechtenstein, Norway or Switzerland, and
  > - Intend to study longer than 90 days
  >   You have to apply for a residence permit at the Alien Registration Office in your university town within your first three months in Germany.

The comment regarding Aufenthaltsdauer seems unrelated to me, it [translates](https://www.udiregelverk.no/PageFiles/3487/Annex%2022_29.06.2016.pdf) to *length of stay to comply with period of validity as indicated in line 2*.

Disclaimer: I am not a lawyer. Enquire with your local Ausländerbehörde. Get the residence permit to be on the safe side in case you are unsure.